# Send drop-down list value to controller depend on another by Ajax and JSON in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a drop-down list depending on another drop-down. 
I used an Ajax call in JSON format to **get** the drop-down list that depends on the first.

My problem now: I can't get the value for selected data to action.

JavaScript code :

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#branchValue").change(
                function () {
                        debugger;  
        var stateId = $("#branchValue").val();  
        $.ajax  
            ({
                async: true ,
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPlatesList", "Properties")',  
                type: 'GET',  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
           data: {  
               'ID': $("#branchValue").val()  
           },  
           success: function (data) {
               var $select = $("#PlateDropDown");
               $("#PlateDropDown").empty();
               $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                   $('<option>', {
                       value: item.ID
                   }).html(item.Plate_Num).appendTo($select);
                 var $test =  $("#PlateDropDown").val()
                   //$("#PlateDropDown").append
                 //    ($('<option></option>').val(item.ID).html(item.Plate_Num));
                 console.log($test);
               });
            },  
            error: function()  
            {  
                 alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..")  
            },  
        }); 
            })
        });

    </script>
```

And GetPlatesList with JsonResult :

```
public JsonResult GetPlatesList(int? ID)
        {
            List<Plates> PlateList = new List<Plates>();
            PlateList = db.Plates.Where(x => x.Dwh_Branches.ID == ID).ToList();
            return Json(PlateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

in view page :

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                الفرع :
                            </label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("BranchID",  null, "-- حدد الفرع --",  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "branchValue" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p class="control-label"> رقم اللوحة : </p>             
                            <select class="form-control" id="PlateDropDown">
                                <option>--حدد الفرع اولا--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Now, in controller Post create Action:

```
public ActionResult CreateProperties(AddPropertyViewModel model,
             FormCollection form)
        {
//code


 int plateID = Int32.Parse(form["PlateDropDown"]);
```

the error is PlateDropDown null String :

row 125:                int plateID = Int32.Parse(form["PlateDropDown"]);

```
[ArgumentNullException: 
Value can not be empty.
اسم المعلمة: String]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12601245
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +120
   System.Int32.Parse(String s) +24
   DrwazhCo.Controllers.PropertiesController.CreateProperties(AddPropertyViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase IdentityImage, HttpPostedFileBase InstrumentImage, List`1 PropImage, FormCollection form) in C:\PROJECT\DrwazhCo\DrwazhCo\Controllers\PropertiesController.cs:125
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +297
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
```

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to code cascading dropdownlists correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form values are POSTed by their `name` attribute.  Your `<select>` doesn't have one:

```
<select class="form-control" id="PlateDropDown">
```

Simply give it a `name` so the browser can POST it to the server

```
<select class="form-control" id="PlateDropDown" name="PlateDropDown">
```

---

It's also recommended to put the expected properties on the view model instead of using the `form` collection and parsing your integer manually.  You can simply add a property to your `AddPropertyViewModel`:

```
public int PlateDropDown { get; set; }
```

This would automatically be bound to the posted value from the named `<select>`.

Comment: thanx alot ... shit i forget the form depend on name not ID :(

Comment: but can explain to me second way ?

Comment: @Anabeil: It's also worth noting that you can use the `@Html.DropDownList` helper to generate the `<select>` markup for you, like you already do above.

Comment: @Anabeil: By using a view model that has the values from your form.  Or, at the very least, putting the values as method arguments on the action.  For example, how does your server-side code currently know the selected value in `BranchID`?  Is that on the `AddPropertyViewModel` object?

Comment: no it's function return ViewBag  
private void BranchesDropDownList(object selectedValue = null)
        {
            var TypeQuery = from d in db.Dwh_Branches
                            orderby d.Name
                            select d;
            ViewBag.BranchID = new SelectList(TypeQuery, "ID", "Name", selectedValue);
        }

Comment: @Anabeil: The ViewBag is used for rendering the view, it has no use in receiving values from a form.  You seem pretty confused about the structure of all of this, and I highly recommend that you start with some vendor tutorials on how to use the ASP.NET MVC Framework.

Comment: i know viewbag structure  ,, and  you can get value by form collection

Comment: @Anabeil: Yes, you *can* technically get values from the form collection.  And in doing so you are not using the MVC Framework capabilities and are adding extra work for yourself and adding extra fragility to the code.  The correct approach is to use the view model.  Like you’re already using for your other values.  Why simultaneously use two different approaches for the same thing?  Just bind the value to the view model instead of manually writing unnecessary code.

Comment: yes , i get your point , i faced problem with common View Model cuz i have one to one relationship and one to many , and i used multi-step form in View , i think it will be best solution/approach ?